# Grails - Mongo: storing images as byte array

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-plugin

I'm struggling storing an image as a byte array in Mongo.
My domain is quite simple

```
class Book {
    String title
    String author
    byte[] photo
    String photoType
}
```

The images are all below 300kB so I would avoid GridFS in the first place.
Once persisted, the photo seems to be stored as a String (always of 11 bytes)

> db.book.find()
>       { "_id" : NumberLong(15), "author" : "", "photo" : "[B@774dba87", "photoType" : "image/jpeg", "title" : "", "version" : 0 }

My controller reads as follows:
    def saveImage() {

```
    def bookInstance
    if(request instanceof MultipartHttpServletRequest) {

        MultipartHttpServletRequest multiRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest)request;
        CommonsMultipartFile file = (CommonsMultipartFile)multiRequest.getFile("photo");

        params.photoType  = file.getContentType()
        print "nb bytes " +file.bytes.length    //TODO

        bookInstance = new Book(params)
        bookInstance.photo=new byte[file.bytes.length]
        bookInstance.photo = file.getBytes()

        def okcontents = ['image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif']
        if (! okcontents.contains(file.getContentType())) {
            flash.message = "Photo must be one of: ${okcontents}"
            render(view:'create', model:[bookInstance:bookInstance])
            return;
        }

        log.info("File uploaded: " + bookInstance.photoType)
    }


    if (!bookInstance.save()) {
        render(view:'create', model:[bookInstance:bookInstance])
        return;
    }
    flash.message = "Book Photo (${bookInstance.photoType}, ${bookInstance.photo.size()} bytes) uploaded."
    redirect(action: "show", id: bookInstance.id)
}
```

I am using Grails 2.2 with the mongo plugin...

Thanks in advance for your hints (and happy 2013 btw!)

Cheers
Philippe

Comment: "so I would avoid GridFS in the first place"... why?!

Comment: I only store small images and GridFS does not seem to be supported by the plugin, unless I'm wrong.

Comment: small images or not, GridFS is the way to go. I'm not a Grails user, but i found this - https://github.com/sergeyy/Grails-plugin-mongodb-gridfs

Answer (score 2):

encodeBase64 / decodeBase64 is the correct approach for you.

The code you provided works fine in previous mongo-gorm plugin release. In the `grails 2.2.0` and `1.1.0.GA mongodb` arrays are not converted properly, the bug GPMONGODB-265 submitted for the case.

Consider using [alternative gorm plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/mongodb-morphia) or pure groovy mongo wrapper [gmongo](https://github.com/poiati/gmongo).

Answer (score 0):

```
def imgStream = file.getInputStream()
byte[] buf = new byte[310000]
int len =imgStream.read(buf, 0, 310000)
ByteArrayOutputStream bytestream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
while(len > 0) {
    bytestream.write(buf, 0, len)
    len =imgStream.read(buf, 0, 310000)
}
bookInstance.photo = bytestream.toByteArray()
bookInstance.save()
```

Comment: I actually found a solution using encodeBase64 / decodeBase64 on the byte array, stored as String in Mongo.  Thanks for your help.