# Gorm MongoDB plugin storing jvm object id instead of byte array data

Tags: java, mongodb, grails, grails-orm, mongodb-java

When I try to store a byte array as a field of a domain class in a grails application, The resulting entry in the mongo database is the [object id of the byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040868/java-syntax-and-meaning-behind-b1ef9157-binary-address) instead of the BinData object which I expected.

Example:

```
class SimpleDomainClass {
    byte[] filed = ['d', 'w', 1, 5, 'r']
}
```

Results in the following in the Mongo DB:

```
{"field" : "[B@29edc561"}
```

I'd expect something more like:

```
{"field" : BinData(0,"blahblahblah")}
```

The [mongo-java driver docs clearly state that this should be stored as a binary object](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Types#JavaTypes-BinaryData) and it is working for us on a similar project with similar configuration.

Does anyone have any idea what might be the issue here?

Library Versions:

- Grails 2.1.0
- plugins.mongodb=1.1.0.GA
- mongo-java-driver 2.10.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're absolutely right, documentation says that it should work. There's a bug [GPMONGODB-265](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPMONGODB-265) in `1.1.0.GA mongodb` plugin which produces arrays saving error.

The same issue discussed: [Grails - Mongo: storing images as byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14160581/grails-mongo-storing-images-as-byte-array/14592676#14592676)

However since you use `grails 2.1.0` you have a change to downgrade mongo gorm plugin to version `1.0.0.GA`, arrays are saved correctly there.

Comment: Thank you. I worked around the issue by encoding to a base 64 string. This is not ideal so I once I get a chance I will try downgrading the plugin.